# How to make an inset like the plane no. 1 from the picture?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

How do I make an inset like the first plane in the following image? Whenever I inset, it comes out like the plane no. 2. Is there a method to do that or do I have to manually do it using loop cuts?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this directly with the inset tool.  Instead I would do this using loop cuts.

Hover near one edge of plane one and type <kbd>R</kbd> to start the cut.  Type <kbd>2</kbd> or scroll the mouse wheel to get two cuts.  Left click twice to finish the cuts:

[image: Plane after adding loop cuts]

Immediately scale the loop cuts along the axis they're perpendicular too, in this case, the x axis, by typing <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to scale.  Use the mouse to scale the loop cuts into position:

[image: Scaled loop cuts]

Now do the same thing, but hover along one of the edges perpendicular to your first choice.  After adding the cuts and scaling on the other axis (In this case Y) you get this:

[image: both loop cuts in place.]